# Is there a way to set socket timeout for Eclipse, Maven, or Java in general?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sockets

I'm in a foreign country and access to some sites is blocked. This is causing problems for Eclipse/Maven, because it will start a Maven operation and wait on network i/o, and there's no way to cancel the task once it's started.

Is there a way to set a network timeout to something like 5s on the outbound connections in Eclipse/Maven, or just in general for Java at the command line?

Thanks!

Comment: `UDP` socket? `TCP` socket? If yes before or after the Three-way handshake? also is it Windows or Linux?

Comment: Maven connects over http, so tcp. I'm running a mac, if that makes a difference